# The input field for command arguments is not displayed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

I’m in the middle of creating a Discord bot that picks out subway stations at random. I’ve got the part where you input the ‘arg’ argument down, but I can’t seem to get the input field to show up.

> discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: TypeError: stn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

- arg argument doesn't appear.
- I use slash command not @bot.command

i install pycord dev verison

Comment: This is likely a command syncing issue. The command has to be synced when the way it is run has changed.